# Adding integer parameter to stored procedure in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, parameter-passing

While trying to pass an integer parameter `@id` to a stored procedure, I get an error `da.Fill(ds)`:

> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@id' to data type int.

I have made sure that integer value is passed and stored procedure contain the correct datatype. What other possibilities are there to rectify this error?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
conn.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("asp_GetTrainingDetail", conn);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: why would a parameter that ends in "Id" be a varchar?

Comment: It seems the column `id` on your table is a `varchar`

Comment: Looks like the c# variable `id` is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know better, [do not use AddWithValue()](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) ... it has to "guess" what datatype you have in your DB based on what you put into the command. It is errorprone and causes unneeded conversions to take place.

Also: use `using(..)` around disposables, especially when using Database-access as it will close your connections even if exceptions arise - not using `using` might let some connection stay unclosed.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection (cs))
{
    using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand ("asp_GetTrainingDetail", conn))
    {
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = id;

        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd1))
        {
            da.Fill (ds);
        }
    }
}
```

Read the link in [do not use AddWithValue()](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for more background infos.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        conn.Open(); SqlCommand cmd1 = new 
        SqlCommand("asp_GetTrainingDetail", conn);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Int.Parse(id));
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
```